# Symfony2 configuration force array type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am developing a Symfony2 application and I want to be able to use a configuration file like this:

```
my_config:
    values: ['val1', 'val2']
```

So I created the following configuration file:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface {
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_config');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('values')
                    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

This configuration, however, lets me add something like:

```
my_config:
    values: ['val1', 123, false]
```

Is there a way to enforce array values to be of type String (e.g. something like `prototype('string')`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no string. Check the file https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/NodeBuilder.php#L27

Node mapping just expect these values

```
$this->nodeMapping = array(
    'variable' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\VariableNodeDefinition',
    'scalar' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\ScalarNodeDefinition',
    'boolean' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\BooleanNodeDefinition',
    'integer' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\IntegerNodeDefinition',
    'float' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\FloatNodeDefinition',
    'array' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\ArrayNodeDefinition',
    'enum' => __NAMESPACE__.'\\EnumNodeDefinition',
);
```

You can check manually in your Conifguration class.
Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array this section for further information.